# How to split metrics on Spring Boot actuator to separate endpoint/port

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.x along with Prometheus.

I would like to expose an endpoint:port which Prometheus can scrape which is separate to the rest of the endpoints on the actuator route.

This is to allow a different security model around the actuator versus metrics, does anyone know if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got from the Slack channel. Hope this helps

the default prometheus endpoint on spring boot is exposed by this class https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java

you could create a second class with a different id under

```
@WebEndpoint(id = "prometheus")
```

This will expose a second endpoint. You can then configure prometheus to scrape the two individual endpoints with different scrape intervals

Answer (score 1):

You can use io.prometheus.

Add to you pom.file

```
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
            <version>${prom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
            <version>${prom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_httpserver</artifactId>
            <version>${prom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And create a class like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MetricConfiguration.class)
public class MetricConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MetricConfiguration.class);
    private HTTPServer server;

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 28080;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
       DefaultExports.initialize();
       server = new HTTPServer(DEFAULT_PORT);
       LOGGER.info("prometheus exporter started on port {}", DEFAULT_PORT);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        server.stop();
        LOGGER.info("prometheus exporter stopped");

    }
}
```

enjoy metrics on app:28080/metrics